# ActionScript 3 to C# translator

Tags: c#, silverlight, actionscript-3

I have some ActionScript 3 code I need to translate to C#. I've started the task manually but it's taking a lot of time.

Have you used a tool that can translate from ActionScript to C#?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Since AS3 and C# does not compile to same kind of binaries, I doubt this would exist.

AS3 leads to an SWF, C# to a server-side dll, an Unity package or a Silverlight application. Such a tool, if it existed, will certainly do fine with basic logic (which is quite similar between AS3 and C#) but would be totally impotent when dealing with more powerful methods or classes.

This is why I think it does not exist :)

Comment: A translator from one language to another it's not impossible. Syntax is very similar between both languages but it's a lot of work to do manually. Of course the API would be a problem but porting logic isn't that difficult: It's mostly changing method signatures, variable declarations and a couple of control flow statements.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert Flash with ActionScript 3 to Silverlight [SWFLight](http://www.swflight.com/) may be useful